# Difference between model.compile's parameter 'weighted_metrics' and model.fit_generator's parameter 'class_weight' in keras?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, image-recognition

While training a keras model for image classification (120 classes from DOG BREED IDENTIFICATION dataset, KAGGLE), I need to balance the classes using class weights which I read somewhere and in examples I have seen people using fit_generator's parameter, class_weight. But I found another parameter in model.compile, weighted_metrics whose description in docs is: 'List of metrics to be evaluated and weighted by sample_weight or class_weight during training and testing'. Shall I be using this? Please explain the purpose of this parameter with any example.

```py
#Calculating Class weights
counter = Counter(train_generator.classes)
max_value = float(max(counter.values()))

CLASS_WEIGHTS = {classid: max_value / num_occurences
                 for classid, num_occurences in counter.items()}
# Model Compile
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=LR),
              loss=categorical_crossentropy,
              metrics=[categorical_accuracy],
              weighted_metrics=None) # <--------------- This parameter

STEPS_PER_EPOCH = train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
VAL_STEPS = val_generator.n//val_generator.batch_size

model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
                    epochs=EPOCHS,
                    callbacks=callback_list,
                    verbose=1,
                    class_weight=CLASS_WEIGHTS,
                    validation_data=val_generator,
                    validation_steps=VAL_STEPS) # USED CLASS_WEIGHTS HERE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use them for your unbalanced dataset.

> weighted_metrics

is a list of metrics that take into account the

> class_weights

that you pass in fit_generator.

So in your example, you can set

```
weighted_metrics=['accuracy']
```

and

`class_weight = {0 : 3, 1: 4}`

The purpose of weighted_metrics parameter is to give a list of metrics that will take into account the class_weights that you pass in fit_generator.

Comment: What metrics do you suggest in this scenario, I have added categorical_crossentropy and categorical_accuracy. Also are the class_weights automatically applied to calculate loss function or do I have to add that manually in the weighted metrics list in model.compile? Thanks for the prompt reply to question though.

Comment: @HimanshuTanwani you could calculate weights using this method
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/18722
Class_weights should be automatically applied to the standard set of loss functions, for example if you  use loss="categorical_crossentropy". The metrics are only for you to see, they don't affect training, only the loss does.

Comment: Note also that the weighting is used in the loss function optimisation, as well as the metric evaluations (on the training data only), see:
https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/#fit-method 
"class_weight: Optional dictionary mapping class indices (integers) to a weight (float) value, used for weighting the loss function (during training only)."